# Splinter: Select From Drop Down

Tags: python, web-scraping, splinter

I have the following code which logs onto the company wiki and navigates to a webpage

```
from splinter import Browser
import pdfkit
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('https://company.wiki.com')
browser.find_by_id('login-link').click()
browser.fill('os_username', 'user')
browser.fill('os_password', 'pass')
browser.find_by_name('login').click()
browser.visit('https://pageoncompany.wiki.com')
```

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOcyR.jpg)

The "normal ajs-menu-item" is the dropdown menu and "action-export-pdf-link" is the option I want to choose. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by select each individually

```
browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/ul/li[4]').click()
browser.find_by_id('action-export-pdf-link').click()
```